# Combined layout not render on NativeScript

Tags: ios, layout, nativescript

Trying to output the following in a NativeScript view

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="loaded">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label class="h1 c-grey" text="(re)volution" />

        <TextField class="c-bg-grey" id="email" text="{{ email }}" hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" />

        <TextField secure="true" text="{{ password }}" hint="Password" />

        <Button text="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary" tap="signIn" />

    </StackLayout>

    <GridLayout columns="50, auto, *" rows="50, auto, *" width="210" height="210" style.backgroundColor="lightgray">
        <Label text="Label 1" row="0" col="0" backgroundColor="red" />
        <Label text="Label 2" row="0" col="1" colSpan="2" backgroundColor="green" />
        <Label text="Label 3" row="1" col="0" rowSpan="2" backgroundColor="blue" />
        <Label text="Label 4" row="1" col="1" backgroundColor="yellow" />
        <Label text="Label 5" row="1" col="2" backgroundColor="orange" />
        <Label text="Label 6" row="2" col="1" backgroundColor="pink" />
        <Label text="Label 7" row="2" col="2" backgroundColor="purple" />
    </GridLayout>

</Page>
```

The emulator only render the last  element. The same happen whatever Layout I try to implement, it's always render the last Layout Container.
What did I missed here? 
What do I need to declare in  to have all layout container in my view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page widgets is ContentView which means that it accepts only one View as child.
So you need to wrap StackLayout and GridLayout in another layout or remove the StackLayout and put it inside GridLayout.

Best solution is to have as few Layouts as possible in order to have better performance.

Comment: Thanks @HHristov it works! Do you mean that is better to avoid multiple type a Layout Container, or even less layout container as possible for better performance?

Comment: Well as any rendering the less elements it needs to display the better, so yes the less layouts/containers/elements the better. Of course you cannot skip all layouts as you do need a good looking UI, simply have it in mind that nesting 3,4,5 etc. containers inside of each other may lead to lower performance.